# Feature toggle WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Is it possible to feature toggle a WatchKit extension? I know I can disable the target by removing it in Build Phases. But I would like to enable the WatchKit extension only for a specific scheme. Building for e.g. production should not bundle the WatchKit app with iOS while building for development should. Can this be achieved?